# How to pass dynamic values (credentials) to CXF Callback Handler in Mule to authenticate with SOAP service

Tags: java, authentication, soap, mule, cxf

I need to authenticate to a SOAP service with username and password.
It works using the CallbackHandler for CXF to pass static values to the service and authenticate.

But i need to authenticate depending on the credentials that are passed into my Mule application, in the HTTP header, params, etc.

I made it work using properties, but still those are static values, the code is below.
I'm using a properties file called 'smarthome-test.properties' that has properties called fp.password and fp.username, fp.username i've set on the CXF Security scope.

**How can i work with invocation properties, so using flowVars typically and use those in the CallbackHandler class?
The Mule Message at that point isn't passed to this CallbackHandler, so what are my options, how can i make it work to retrieve values from flowVars, or maybe store them somewhere first, pass in an object?**

```
package com.smarthomes.soap;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;

import org.apache.ws.security.WSPasswordCallback;

public class ClientPasswordCallback implements CallbackHandler {

    //ParseCredentials Credentials;

    static final ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("smarthome-test");

    private String passwordPropertyName = "fp.password";

    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {

        WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];
        if ("mydummyuserName".equals(pc.getIdentifier())) {
           //pc.setPassword("mydummypassWord"); 
            pc.setPassword(bundle.getString(getPasswordPropertyName()));
        }

    }
    public String getPasswordPropertyName() {
        return passwordPropertyName;
    }
    public void setPasswordPropertyName(String passwordPropertyName) {
        this.passwordPropertyName = passwordPropertyName;
    }

}
```

Details about CXF client

```
<cxf:proxy-client  payload="envelope" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" soapVersion="1.2" doc:name="CXF Proxy Client">
    <cxf:ws-security>
        <cxf:ws-config>
            <cxf:property key="action" value="UsernameToken"/>
            <cxf:property key="passwordType" value="PasswordText"/>
            <cxf:property key="passwordCallbackClass" value="com.smarthomes.soap.ClientPasswordCallback"/>
            <cxf:property key="user" value="${fp.username}"/>
        </cxf:ws-config>
    </cxf:ws-security>
</cxf:proxy-client>
```

Answer (score 1):

In server part you can use passwordCallbackRef instead of passwordCallbackClass to provide an instance. I do not know if property is available for client because documentation is not too good

Try this on ws-config and provide password in the clientpasswordcallback singleton

```
 <cxf:property key="passwordCallbackRef">
              <ref bean="myPasswordCallback"/>
           </cxf:property>


<bean id="myPasswordCallback"
  class="com.mycompany.ClientPasswordCallback"/>
```